# git: how to recover a deleted branch that is not merged

Tags: git

I have accidently deleted my branch from the repo without merging the branch into another. Is there a way I can recover files and that branch itself or I can't?

Answer (score 2):

Branch is really a label to a commit. And commit are rarely removed - only when there is not enough space or you explicitly do a garbage collection.

You can look at the previous HEAD which is a label for your currently checked-out branch with `git reflog`. When you find the commit you are interested in, you can check it out and make a new branch pointing to this commit.

Comment: using git reflog I am able to see the commits that I did in the deleted branch. Will work on further.Thanks.